# Why embe.rjs does not see my controller method in template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In the project, I have template input:

```
 {{#if (communicationPreferenceIs 'Phone')}}
    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 form-label">
                            Phone<i class="required">*</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            {{input-validation
                                    type="text"
                                    required=true
                                    class="form-control"
                                    value=model.phone
                                    placeholder="Phone"
                                    pattern="[0-9]*"
                                    maxlength="30"
                                    onkeydown=""
                                    key-down="validateInput"
                            }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
    {{/if}}
```

I need a conditional render and wrap it in if-construction. In it, I'm using the method `communicationPreferenceIs` from the controller to check the value. Here is its code:

```
App.EditController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
communicationPreferenceIs: function(preference) {
    const model = this.get('model');
    if (!model.communicationPreference || !model.communicationPreference.name) {
      return false;
    }

    const currentPreference = model.communicationPreference.name;

    return currentPreference === preference;
  }.property('model.communicationPreference'),
}
```

So, on render, I'm getting an ember error:

```
"Assertion Failed: A helper named 'communicationPreferenceIs' could not be found"
```

I experimented and found out, that this method worked:

```
communicationPreferencePhone: function() {
    const model = this.get('model');
    return (
        model.communicationPreference &&
        model.communicationPreference.name === 'Phone'
    );
  }.property('model.communicationPreference'),
```

if I use it in mode:

```
{{#if communicationPreferencePhone }}
```

it works well. How to make more universal `communicationPreferenceIs` work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the this page? [Global Helper Functions](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_global-helper-functions)

To use globally available helper functions, you'll want to place them in the app/helpers folder.

And in the classic system, you'd use kebab-case for referencing the helper.

so,

1. define `app/helpers/communication-preference-is.js`

```
export default ....
```

2. call it via `{{communication-preference-is this.model "Phone"}}`
   or as a sub-expression via `{{otherFunction (communication-preference-is this.model "Phone")}}`
   as would occur in an if statement:

   ```
   {{#if (communication-preference-is this.model "Phone")}}

   {{/if}}
   ```

Note on syntax:

- `{{ }}` for escaping HTML
- `( )` for sub-expressions (e.g: invoke communication-preferenc-is)
- `{{#` start of block
- `{{/` end of block

Spatially:

```
{{                     }} for escaping HTML
  #                       start of block
                as |  |   define local variables within the block
  /                       end of block
    (         )           sub expression
      (     )             sub expression (nested)
```

---

Note that prior to ember-source 4.5, helpers had to be wrapped in an extra function, `helper`

```
// app/helpers/communication-preference-is.js
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export default helper(function communicationPreferenceIs(positionalArgs, namedArgs) {
    let [model, type] = positionalArgs;

    return (
        model.communicationPreference &&
        model.communicationPreference.name === type
    );
});
```

and after ember-source@4.5, you'd be able to

```
export default function communicationPreferenceIs(model, type) {
    return (
        model.communicationPreference &&
        model.communicationPreference.name === type
    );
}
```

And using Ember Polaris (supported at 3.28+), you'd import the helper rather than rely on globals:

```
import communicationPreferenceIs from 'app-name/helpers/communication-preference-is';

<template>
  {{communicationPreferenceIs @model "Phone"}}
</template>
```

But that point you may want an `app-name/helpers` file where you can import anything from rather than have one import per helper.

Comment: yes I see. I need to get model in helper method: this.get('model') and in helper its unavailable

Comment: you would probably need to pass it -- I've updated my answer with an example implementation

Comment: its not clear how to use this helper in template. {{communicationPreferenceIs @model "Phone"}} is not if block. does it have closing block?

Comment: yes, you may be interested in https://tutorial.glimdown.com/ and https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/ which covers the syntax.

I've updated the question to use if syntax -- when escaping HTML, you always use `{{}}` and then sub-expressions use `()` -- and that's the whole syntax! it's consistent for modifiers, helpers, you name it. it's quite simple 